# Why am I getting two different url strings from get_permalink($post->ID)?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have written some shortcode functions to display my custom post type posts, listings, in different ways. However, using get_permalink(ID) to create the link to the post is not consistent.

I have looked at many other posts with solutions like adding the rewrite parameter to the custom post_type args, but I cannot seem to figure this out.

Here's my code for creating the post type:

```
$args = array_merge([
                'label'               => __('Listing', 'text_domain'),
                'description'         => __('Custom post type', $text_domain),
                'labels'              => $labels,
                'supports'            => ['title', 'author', 'thumbnail'],
                'taxonomies'          => ['post_tag', 'category'],
                'hierarchical'        => TRUE,
                'public'              => TRUE,
                'show_ui'             => TRUE,
                'show_in_menu'        => TRUE,
                'menu_position'       => 5,
                'show_in_admin_bar'   => TRUE,
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE,
                'can_export'          => TRUE,
                'has_archive'         => TRUE,
                'exclude_from_search' => FALSE,
                'publicly_queryable'  => TRUE,
                'capability_type'     => 'page',
                'rewrite' => FALSE
//              'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'listings'],
//              'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'listings', 'with_front' => FALSE],
            ]);

            register_post_type('listings', $args);
```

As you can see, I've tried a few different rewrite options. Here is what I get from get_permalink when trying different permalink structures:

**Permalinks set to Plain:**

1. [base]/?post_type=listings&p=[ID]  <-- expected result and displays post
2. [base]/?listings=[post_name] <-- this returns 404

**Peramlinks set to Post Name**

1. [base]/listings/[post_name] <-- this returns 404 consistently